# Anyone know how to use the "¥" symbol in terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, passwords, password-encryption, password-hash

Currently working on an assignment to modify passwords passwd file to replace placeholder "x" with a hash function (SHA-512). The following command was given to use in vim:

```
:s/x:/¥=system('mkpasswd -m sha-512 password | tr “¥n” “:”')/
```

Anyone know how to insert the "¥" w/o copying and pasting? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Why do you need to use that special character in the first place? Also, the arguments to `tr` should be in ASCII single quotes or double quotes, not curly quotes.